# Where is this mvc:view-controller behaviour documented?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring MVC application, and found this line at *webmvc-config.xml*:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/testView" />
```

I've tried it and I know that when I hit **/myTestPath** from the browser, Spring is mapping the request to a view defined with Tiles as follows:

```
<definition name="testView" extends="default">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/testPage.jspx" />
</definition>
```

But I don't know how and why. Spring documentation says:

*"Behind the scenes, mvc:view-controller registers a ParameterizableViewController that selects a view for rendering"*, and shows this example:

```
<!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "welcome" view -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome" />
```

I understand ParameterizableViewController, a simple controller that returns a named view based on its viewName property.

But I can't find anything regarding what goes on if I don't specify a viewName when declaring a "mvc:view-controller" line.

I would sleep better tonight if someone could enlighten me.... ú__ù
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the view name the behavior will be exactly same as if you specify a `@RequestMapping` method with a void return type:

Quoting Spring framework docs:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-return-types

> void if the method handles the response itself (by writing the response content directly, declaring an argument of type ServletResponse / HttpServletResponse for that purpose) or if the view name is supposed to be implicitly determined through a RequestToViewNameTranslator (not declaring a response argument in the handler method signature).

i.e A component called `RequestToViewNameTranslator` tries to figure out the view name based on the request path.

Here are some samples from the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.html) of RequestToViewNameTranslator:

```
http://test:8080/gamecast/display.html -> display

http://test:8080/gamecast/displayShoppingCart.html -> displayShoppingCart

http://test:8080/gamecast/admin/index.html -> admin/index
```

The same logic will apply in your case, `/testView` will translate to `testView` view name

Comment: Hi Biju Kunjummen! First, THANK you very much for your time... :) So, if I have understand you, this RequestToViewNameTranslator component is called by default when no view name is implicitly specified, right? And, can you tell me how do you know that ParameterizableViewController behaves like a @RequestMapping with void type? I mean, is this documented? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes @RocíoGarcíaLuque, it is mentioned in the javadocs :-), you may have missed it - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ParameterizableViewController.html

Comment: "if this property is not set, a null view name will be returned directing the caller to calculate the view name from the current request"... thank you very much!